# Graphics card causes motherboard to delay power off

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, gpu, post

Recently a glass of fruit juice was dumped into my tower. I immediately scrapped the motherboard and power supply unit, replacing both, and attempted to salvage both the RAM, GPU, and the CPU. I took every component out, and meticulously cleaned everything with isopropyl alcohol and electrical contact cleaner, attempting to clean the dried stains off of my graphics card PCB (fan faces the bottom). The CPU and RAM were relatively okay, even before cleaning.

After replacing the motherboard and PSU, the computer boots up and everything seemingly runs just as it did before. The only problem i've got now is when I send a shutdown signal from my OS, the OS shuts down properly and the GPU cycles the monitors off, but there is about a 30 second delay before the mobo shuts off. Turning it back on is similar, I cycle on and there is about a 20-30 second delay before it begins posting and booting my OS. As well, if I attempt to switch from my GUI to a virtual console within the OS, the OS makes the switch but cycles off my monitors instead of showing tty1, with no errors reported from the kernal or rsyslog. Switching back from tty1 to the GUI, again about a 20-30 second delay, I get a beep from the motherboard, and my monitors cycle on and I can resume from the GUI.

I believe I've singled this out to my graphics card. If I remove the GPU from the system, everything seems to go back to normal, OS shuts down relatively quick and posts as normal.

I guess what I'm asking is that before I go back to scrubbing more juice off the GPU, is there anything I can do to fix this issue specifically? I'm still not 100% sure it's the GPU and not something wrong with the motherboard itself as I replaced it at the same time as the GPU (ie. PCI bus). Is this something a graphics card can be responsible for?

And and all advice would be greatly appreciated. I'd prefer not to have to replace the card as everything else works okay except for this one thing.

Thanks for reading my wall of text

~ llldino

Comment: It definitely sounds like the GPU is the hardware that is causing the issue. I'm just unsure if trying to clean the GPU more will solve any problems. If there still is some residue on the GPU I would refrain from inserting it onto the motherboard in the first place. I would not want to chance ruining the PCIe slot.

Answer (score 1):

I assume u r running windows. That delay would be Windows querying a component (seemingly in your case the GPU) and not getting the response it is looking for either fast enough or not at all.
The best thing to do when one spills anything on electronics is to wash it in fresh water (a dishwasher will work) and put it into an oven on min temp for at least 24 hours to dry it. The longer the better. (We did just that at an industrial service outfit I worked for).
U might look at the event viewer to see if there r any errors or warnings reported. That my give u a good clue.

Comment: I'm running linux, but thanks for your response anyways.